# How to connect Slider with Database?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

My model represents an assembly line with 27 cycles and a defined cycletime. The product which has to get assembled is transported trough the assembly line by AGVs. On each AGV is one product.
Because the cycle areas have different lengths the AGV speed [m/sec] differs from cycle to cycle.

I created an excel file database with several cycle times in the first column and their respective AGV speeds for each cycle in the following columns.

Now I want to simulate those different cycle times. I created a `Move To` block and set agent's speed to variable `v_agvSpeed` which is on `Main`. I need the variable because I want to change the agent's speed by a Slider.
Where I do not get further is how to connect my database with the variable `v_agvSpeed`? When I set my Slider for Example on 60.0 secs cycletime the variable `v_agvSpeed` has to get assigned to the right cycletime and the respective cycle out of the database.

Two images of the case:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knqWD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogSDD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the database query wizard to query the table for your slider's value, something like this in the slider action code:

```
v_agvSpeed = (int) selectFrom(cyclespeedavg)
     .where(cyclespeedavg.cycletime.eq((double)slider.getValue()))
     .firstResult(cyclespeedavg.cycle1)
```